# How to get custom image size for image uploaded in Customizer

Tags: php, theme-development, images, themes, theme-customizer

I'm using the customizer to upload an image. The code I have below displays the full size image ok but I would like to instead display a custom size of that image that I created below that.

This is the code in my template file:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'image-1' , get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default.jpg' ); ?>">
```

This is the code in my `functions.php` file to add the custom size:

```
add_image_size( 'image-thumbnail', 525, 350, true );
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, your mod is storing the complete path to the image as a string. That leaves you little alternative but to do a search and replace on the string:

```
$img = get_theme_mod('image-1');
if (!empty ($img)) {
  $img = preg_replace ('.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$','-525x350$0');
  if (!file_exists($img)) $img = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default.jpg';
    }
  else if (!file_exists($img)) $img = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default.jpg';
```

In words. Get the mod. If it exists search `$img` for the occurence of `jpg|jpeg|png|gif` at the end of the string and then prepend it with the image size, eg `...image-525x350.jpg`. If that file does not exist, use the default. If there is no mod, also use the default.

Answer (score 0):

Working from cjbj's answer, you may need to add delimiters to have your preg_replace work correctly:

```
$img = get_theme_mod('image-1');
if (!empty ($img)) {
  $img = preg_replace ('/.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/','-525x350$0');
  if (!file_exists($img)) $img = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default.jpg';
  }
else if (!file_exists($img)) $img = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default.jpg';
```